# Additing gtf file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I had to get only ENSEMBLE non-chromosomal pseudogenes from given gtf file
add additional attribute field "filtered" with value "manually" for each of the annotated pseudogenes and save as new file. So I had to filter the given file by containing "ENSEMBLY" "pseudogenes" and not containing "Chr" save it in new file and add to the last column additional property(filter-manually). Could you tell me how can I do this using awk or sed preferably?

```
    ##description: evidence-based annotation of the human genome (GRCh38), version 29 (Ensembl 94)
##provider: GENCODE
##contact: gencode-help@ebi.ac.uk
##format: gtf
##date: 2018-08-30
chr1    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name 
"DDX11L1-202"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    11869   12227   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1
-202"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00002234944.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12721   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1
-202"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00003582793.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1
-202"; exon_number 3; exon_id "ENSE00002312635.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      12010   13670   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; tr
anscript_name "DDX11L1-201"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12010   12057   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript
_name "DDX11L1-201"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001948541.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12179   12227   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript
_name "DDX11L1-201"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00001671638.2"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12697   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unp
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Which lines in the example do describe a `ENSEMBLE non-chromosomal pseudogene`? and why (what are the related strings) ?

Comment: This are lines that match patterns:ENSEMBL exon 169224 169502 . - . gene_id "ENSG00000284215.2"; transcript_id "ENST00000639764.2"; gene_type "pseudogene"; gene_name "AC245056.4"; transcript_type "pseudogene"; transcript_name "AC245056.4-201"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00003804365.1"; level 3; tag "basic"; Filtered: manually;

Comment: Actually I have managed to do this but maybe there is better solution using only awk?

Comment: I have done this.                                                                                               grep -v "##" gencode.v29.chr_patch_hapl_scaff.basic.annotation.gtf | grep -v "chr" | grep "pseudogene" | grep "ENSEMBL"| awk '{$0=$0" Filtered: manually;"}{print $0}' > gencode.v29.filtered.gtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Awk anyway, you don't need `grep` at all.

Also, less crucially, modifying `$0` is mildly wasteful. `print` lets you specify precisely what you want to print.

```
awk '!/##/ && !/chr/ && /pseudogene/ && /ENSEMBL/ {
       print $0" Filtered: manually;"}' gencode.v29.chr_patch_hapl_scaff.basic.annotation.gtf > gencode.v29.filtered.gtf
```